# Wordpress wp-admin redirects to home page

Tags: plugins

Activated custom plugin after that it redirect to `https://siteurl/wp-admin` . Trying to login again but it redirects to home page `https://siteurl`
Things I tried:

1. Change theme name and activated default theme
2. Renamed `plugins` folder to `plugins-old` and also changed the values in `wp-option` but no luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what your problem is and what are you trying to do. Please read [How to ask](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Try to login with this `http://siteurl/wp-login.php` instead of this `https://siteurl/wp-admin`.

Comment: @rishabh http://siteurl/wp-login.php tried .. but didn't helped me